# How to count the number of new id's present in each month(id should not be present in previous months)

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to get the count of id's for each month which are not present in the next month.
Below is the sql I have currently written but doesn't look like a good approach.Is there any better way to do this?There will be multiple months in the query.

```
select count(distinct id) from  table1
    where bill_yearmo='202007' and id not in (select 
    acct_id from table1
    where bill_yearmo='202006' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select first_bill_yearmo, count(*) as num_starts
from (select id, min(bill_yearmo) as first_bill_yearmo
      from table1
      group by id
     ) i
group by first_bill_yearmo;
```